# cordova iframe not working with 2 errors

Tags: html, visual-studio, cordova, iframe, apache-cordova

I had a problem. I'm running an iframe tag in visual studio 2017 that uses cordava apache. When I run the app it doesn't show the webpage because something has blocked it or something like that. 
When I check the log I see 2 errors:

- " Refused to frame 'https://googel.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback. "

- " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) "

These are 2 errors I get.
I had also changed my congif.xml and I have

```html
<allow-navigation href="https://google.com" />
   <access origin="https://google.com" />
```

and here's my iframe code.

```html
 <iframe src="https://googel.com"></iframe>
```

What is the problem? What should I do?

Thank you

Regards

---

**UPDATE**

After removing the mat security it worked. So I'll change my question:

Is removing the security meta bad for the application?

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should comment out this meta section.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```